# Cannot set property 'textContent' of null error

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am getting this error in SAP UI5 app.

```
updateFinished: function (count) {
    itemCount = count.getParameters().total;
    var labelId = thats2.getView().byId("page").getCustomHeader().getContentMiddle()[0].sId;
    document.getElementById(labelId).textContent = "Requests (" + itemCount + ")";
}
```

what is wrong with the code. Do I need to do null check before assignment?
Thanks

Comment: As an application developer, you should never access DOM references and manipulate its internal values directly but use high-level APIs. Is this question still relevant? If yes, I can add an answer with more details. Otherwise, please remove this question since it's less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById()` tries to retrieve an element by using it's HTML id attribute, which may or may not exist.

```
var labelId = thats2.getView().byId("page").getCustomHeader().getContentMiddle()[0].sId;
```

Here you are getting the **UI5 element id**, mapped to HTML attribute `data-sap-ui`.

In order to get the UI5 element no matter if it has HTML id attribute or not you can do:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId(labelId).textContent = "Requests (" + itemCount + ")";
```

Anyway, it'd be still a good practice to check if `sap.ui.getCore().byId(labelId)` exists.

Comment: You should avoid sap.ui.getCore().byId(id), instead use this.byId(id).